# Grails: How to use exists/notExists within createCriteria?

Tags: hibernate, grails

According to this jira ticket ([Support for Subqueries.exists() etc. in HibernateCriteriaBuilder)](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/commit/fc6cd2439fe774f2c72595ad12812f65b2002824)), the exists/notExists criterion method has been added to HibernateCriteriaBuilder.  I'm looking for help in the usage of this feature because I can't find any documentation.

The 'exists' method appears to take a QueryableCriteria object as a parameter but I'm unfamiliar with this class and can't find any useful documentation on this either.

My simplified class structure:

```
class Foo {
  static hasMany = [fooBars: FooBar]
}

class FooBar {
  static belongsTo = [Foo, Bar]

  Foo foo
  Bar bar
}

class Bar {
  String division
  static hasMany = [fooBars: FooBar]
}
```

My goal is to find Foo's that either:
a ) don't have an associated Bar
or
b ) the associated Bar's division is in a specified list of Strings (or not in a list of specified Strings)

Right now I'm using a sqlRestriction and it's working correctly, but I would prefer to use the HibernateCriteriaBuilder methods:

```
def crit = Foo.createCriteria()

def results = crit.list() {
  sqlRestriction("""  not exists (
    select 1 
    from 
      Foo_Bar fb 
      inner join Bar b 
        on Foo_Bar.bar_id = b.id 
    where 
      fb.foo_id = this_.id 
        and b.DIVISION in ('bad', 'terrible') )
   """)
}
```

My code is using 'not exists' but an example of 'exists' syntax would help just the same.

Thanks

Comment: Has there any non-HQL approach for this yet?